# When calling a Symfony Console command from another, how do I specify values for VALUE_IS_ARRAY options?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a command which has the following option:

```
protected function configure(): void
{
    $this->addOption(
        'alias',
        'a',
        InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY | InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
        "Add an Apache alias",
    );
}
```

When I run this on the command line it would be done like so:

```
php my-script my-command --alias=alias1 --alias=alias2 --alias=alias3
```

I want to [call this command from another one](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html). I have the following:

```
// ...
$myScript = $this->getApplication()->find('my-command');
$myScript->run(ArrayInput([
    '--alias' => 'alias1',
    '--alias' => 'alias2',
    '--alias' => 'alias3',
]), $output)
```

Obviously this will only pass one alias as the associative Array only supports unique keys.

How would I refactor the above to support arrays of values?

Comment: It could work by just ommitting the `--alias` like in the example `bin/console app:greet Fabien Ryan Bernhard`   here https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html you should be able to use `ArrayInput(['alias1', 'alias2', 'alias3'])`

Comment: the arrayInput needs to be the last argument though to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appears I hadn't tried *everything*. Doing the following worked:

```
$myScript->run(ArrayInput([
    '--alias' => ['alias1', 'alias2', 'alias3'],
]), $output);
```